# creating dome model by three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, modeling

How can I create dome model like this picture by three.js ? I have the model eqution.

[image]

Comment: If you have the model equation, you can wrap a plane or distort a cylinder or a cone.

Comment: @prisoner849 , thank you . Could you please tell me how can I wrap a plane? any link to docs please ?

Comment: How to change coordinates of vertices in a geometry or a buffer geometry?